# Range.Formula in VBA not accepting input range

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

So I have this code which finds a specific string on a sheet called `Master Trainings` and finds the address of the cell to the right of it. That is all fine. Right before this, I have a piece of code which creates a line and puts that same text in a cell, say D4. `w` here is the r1c1 address of the row above (i.e. `3` in this case). I have `NewCourseCell` which returns the address of the cell I want perfectly, but I am not sure why the last line fails to create the formula I want inside that cell.

```
Dim findRng25 As Range
Dim foundRng25 As Range
Set findRng25 = Sheets("Master Trainings").Range("A:A")
Set foundRng25 = findRng25.Find(Cells(w + 1, 4).Value)

Dim C25 As Variant
C25 = Cells(foundRng25.Row, foundRng25.Column + 1).Address(0, 0)

NewCourseCell = Cells(w + 1, 5).Address
Range(NewCourseCell).Formula = "=B9*'Master Trainings'!" & C25 & ",0)"
```

Comment: *"last line fails to create the formula"* what does "fails" mean? any error message? your string would produce something like `=B9*'Master Trainings'!C25,0)` so you have a `,0)` in the end that doesn't make any sense. You cannot close a bracket in a formula that wasn't opened before. • Try to go through your code step-by-step (with F8) and check the values of your variables (see [Excel Easy - Debugging](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)).

Comment: Not sure about your formula, if you wanted to add the variable c25 to it then....... `="=B9*'Master Trainings'!" & c25`

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, I also dimmed c25 as a string, when I tried out the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by @PEH, this part of the formula is a bit useless - `",0)"`. There is only one `)` and the `,0` is not required.

This is some minimal code, that works, if you have `Master Trainings` worksheet:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim c25 As String
    c25 = "D10"
    Range("B2").Formula = "=B9*'Master Trainings'!" & c25

End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah, this was a bit of code I copied form something similar that was using a different formula that was useless in this case. All that I needed to do was remove that bit of stuff at the end per your recommendation. Thank you.